# Inline menu appearing with mouseover

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, jsp

What I am looking for is an inline menu, that pops up by a mouseover event.  Does anyone know how to do something like this? The way it currently works in my program is very complicated (using multiple servlets and JSON).

Answered

Comment: Just `"addEventListener"` a `"mouseover"` event on the dropdowns to display the menu.

Comment: I suggest you start your search by looking at Suckerfish http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Comment: Thanks guys, Suckerfish should be capable of doing what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a div element that will house the menu items that you require. hide it by default and give it absolute positioning. Add a mouseover event that will calculate the position based on which element you are hovering over and set this element's position to that and make it visible.